# Search multiple parameters in one search box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have a asp net "site" that functions as a data input device. I added a search box to it to make it easier for people to find specific results in order to add data. My question is currently I have it so people search by the PONumber and it returns relevant data-rows. I just wanted to know if it was possible to keep the POnumber search but to also make it so people can search by classcodes as well within that same search box without making another one.

Like I mentioned I have a working version that does what I want it to do and I'm happy with it for the most part. Just looking at options.

```
 Private Sub SearchVen()
       Dim Constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PurchaseOrderConnectionString").ConnectionString
       Using Con As New SqlConnection(Constr)
           Using cmd As New SqlCommand
               Dim searchword As String = "SELECT PurchaseOrder.PoId, PurchaseOrder.Vendor_Name, PurchaseOrder.POAmount,PurchaseOrder.DateFrom, PurchaseOrder.DateTo, PurchaseOrder.Balance, PurchaseOrder.CodeId, PurchaseOrder.PoNumber, BPNumber, ClassCode.CodeId AS Expr1, ClassCode.CodeDefinition, PurchaseOrder.Notes FROM PurchaseOrder INNER JOIN ClassCode ON PurchaseOrder.CodeId = ClassCode.CodeId"
               If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox11.Text.Trim()) Then
                   searchword += " Where PurchaseOrder.PONumber Like @POnumber + '%'"
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PONumber", TextBox11.Text.Trim())
               End If
               cmd.CommandText = searchword
               cmd.Connection = Connection
               Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                   Dim dt As New DataTable()
                   sda.Fill(dt)
                   GridView1.DataSourceID = ""
                   GridView1.DataSource = dt
                   GridView1.DataBind()
               End Using
           End Using
       End Using
   End Sub
```

Edit1:

```
                Dim searchword As String = "SELECT PurchaseOrder.PoId, PurchaseOrder.Vendor_Name, PurchaseOrder.POAmount,PurchaseOrder.DateFrom, PurchaseOrder.DateTo, PurchaseOrder.Balance, PurchaseOrder.CodeId, PurchaseOrder.PoNumber, BPNumber, ClassCode.CodeId AS Expr1, ClassCode.CodeDefinition, PurchaseOrder.Notes FROM PurchaseOrder INNER JOIN ClassCode ON PurchaseOrder.CodeId = ClassCode.CodeId"
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox11.Text.Trim()) Then
                    searchword += " Where PurchaseOrder.PONumber Like @POnumber + '%'" Or "ClassCode.CodeDefinition like @CodeDefinition + '%'"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PONumber", TextBox11.Text.Trim())
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodeDefinition", TextBox11.Text.Trim())
                End If
```

Tried putting this in and get a input string is in incorrect format error message.

Comment: Of course it is.  You just put an `OR` operator into your `WHERE` clause.  This is just basic logic.  If you had a list of names and I gave you a letter, could you not search for names that had that letter in the given name or the family name?  Of course you could.  Anyone could.  You're asking how to do that.

Comment: (1) AddWithValue is not a good choice, as explained [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) (2) The parameter name is "@PONumber", i.e. with the leading "@". (3) It may work better if you add the "%" onto the value of the parameter instead of inside the query.